# Is a categorical coproduct of epimorphisms (monomorphisms) always an epimorphism (a monomorphism)?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, products

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category (that does not necessary have a coproduct for every collection of objects).  Suppose that we have two families of objects $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(B_i)_{i\in I}$ in $\mathbf{C}$ indexed by the same index set $I$.  Assume further that there exist coproducts $A$ and $B$ of $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ and of $(B_i)_{i\in I}$, respectively.  If $f_i:A_i\to B_i$ are morphisms for all $i\in I$, then there exists a unique morphism $f:A\to B$, which is the coproduct of $(f_i)_{i\in I}$.

I know the following results.  The morphism $f$ need not be monic, even if all $f_i$ are monic.   If $\mathbf{C}$ is an abelian category and if all $f_i$ are epic, then $f$ is epic.  Therefore, I have two related questions.  All references are very welcome.

> **Question I.**  In general (where $\mathbf{C}$ need not be an abelian category), does $f$ have to be epic, provided that all $f_i$ are epic?  If so, could you please provide a proof or a reference?  If not, could you please provide a counterexample (for a finite $I$ and for an infinite $I$, if possible)?
>
> **Question II.**  If $\mathbf{C}$ is an abelian category and if all $f_i$ are monic, then does it follow that $f$ is monic?  If so, could you please provide
> a proof or a reference?  If not, could you please provide a counterexample (for a finite $I$ and for an infinite $I$, if possible)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Question 1: Yes. The $I$-coproduct-functor $\bigsqcup_I\colon\prod_{i\in I}\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C}$ is left-adjoint (its right adjoint is the diagonal functor $\Delta_{\mathbf{C}}^I\colon \mathbf{C}\to\prod_{i\in I}\mathbf{C}$), hence always preserves epimorphisms.

Question 2: No, in general (even if $\mathbf{C}$ is $I$-coproduct-complete). Cocomplete abelian categories with such property are called *satisfying axiom AB4*. See [nlab article on Grothendieck axioms](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/additive+and+abelian+categories). Some counterexamples were discussed on SE; see, for example [Zhen Lin's answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674482/example-of-epimorphisms-such-that-the-product-is-not-an-epimorphism-in-the-categ). The original source for this axiom is the Tôhoku paper (A.Grothendieck, "Sur quelques points d'algèbre homologique", 1957).

Regarding the changes in your question after edits:

In the situation when $\mathbf{C}$ is not $I$-coproduct-complete, the previous proof becomes not entirely correct (probably it may be improved by regarding relative adjoint functors, but I don't think it's relevant to this question). However, there is a straightforward proof of this fact: 
$$
(g\circ f=h\circ f)\Rightarrow(g\circ f\circ s_i=h\circ f\circ s_i)\Rightarrow(g\circ s_i\circ f_i=h\circ s_i\circ f_i)\Rightarrow(g\circ s_i=h\circ s_i)\Rightarrow(g\circ h),
$$
where $g$ and $h$ are arbitrary morphisms of $\mathbf{C}$ with domain $B$ and $s_i$, $i\in I$, are canonical injections of coproducts.

As for the finite $I$ in your second question: there is no such counterexamples. An abelian category is always finitely complete, finitely cocomplete and finite coproducts coincide with finite products, hence if $I$ is finite, then the $I$-coproduct functor of an abelian (or even additive) category is both left- and right-adjoint, hence exact. So the axiom AB4 requires only that the infinite coproducts of monomorphisms should be monomorphisms.